# Playing multiple files using mpv.exe in Delphi7

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I have try code from @moskito-x like this

```
var alamat:AnsiString;  
begin  
      TntOpenDialog1.Execute;  
      alamat:=TntOpenDialog1.FileName;  
      ShellExecute(0, nil, 'E:\Generic\MPV\mpv.exe', PChar('"'+alamat+'"'), nil, SW_NORMAL);  
end;
```

It works fine until then I choose to select multiple file only 1 files can be played. I want to do writing code like @David Heffernan's clue in using ShellExecuteExW but my Windows has a problem and cannot open hlp file. I have search entire web about it and still don't understand how to use it and how to make it work

Comment: I have problem with selecting multiple files using ShellExecuteExW. And I don't know how to use it even if I've tried to learn from much exsample. I wanna select multiple files(eg. some movie, .avi, .flv, .mp4 etc.) and play them using mpv.exe

Comment: `ShellExecuteExW` has absolutely nothing to do with opening multiple files in an open dialog. Iterate through the resulting list and execute each one by one, just like in the loop below in my answer.

Comment: On the other hand, are you asking how to open all of these multiple files in one single instance of this application? Because that's a whole different story.

Comment: Sorry for my bad english. mpv.exe can play file like this  >>>mpv.exe file1.flv file2.mp4 file3.mkv  >>>I want to do something like if I select multiple files using TntOpenDialog it will give me result like file1.flv file2.mp4 file3.mkv and then I can play it using mpv.exe, but I don't know how to do it

Comment: Choosing which files to open is the easy part which you apparently have already figured out. Your title is okay, but your description seemingly asks something else. Chances are, you'll have to consult the vendors of this application to know how to load multiple files at once, or find the documentation for this application. Your question should be scoped to only this one topic, leaving out the irrelevant part of using an open dialog or calling `ShellExecuteExW`.

Comment: @Mohammad You were badly advised at the last question. Why are you using Tnt Unicode components but then converting to AnsiString?

Comment: Two side-notes on your code. 1) When calling TntOpenDialog1.Execute you should observe its result to ensure it's True. If False, you shouldn't continue. 2) You shouldn't hard-code the EXE path in your application. It's very likely that it may reside elsewhere, and you should detect this in advance, wherever it may be.

Comment: I was going to show you how to use `ShellExecuteExW`, but not I don't want to because you've made it clear that you aren't interested in understanding. I think that's a shame.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `mpv.exe` allows you to specify multiple files in a single command line, you can simply loop through the `TntOpenDialog.Files` list concatenating the filenames together into a single string, and then pass that string to `ShellExecuteW()` as the parameter list for `mpv.exe`, eg:

```
uses
  ..., TntWideStrUtils;

var
  alamat: WideString;  
  i: Integer;
begin  
  if TntOpenDialog1.Execute then
  begin
    alamat := WideQuotedStr(TntOpenDialog1.Files[0], '"');
    for i := 1 to TntOpenDialog1.Files.Count-1 do begin
      alamat := alamat + ' ' + WideQuotedStr(TntOpenDialog1.Files[i], '"');
    end;
    ShellExecuteW(0, nil, 'E:\Generic\MPV\mpv.exe', PWideChar(alamat), nil, SW_NORMAL);  
  end;
end;
```

Comment: You beat me to it :-/ I was just digging through their docs and just came to that and came here to answer, to find yours :-)

Comment: I don't have documentation for TNTWare but I found some TNTWare-related source code on [Google Code](https://code.google.com/p/historypp/source/browse/#svn%2FtntControls%2FSource), so I dug through that :)

Comment: Sorry, Invalid Typecast error appear when I try to run this program. I have done like you have write bot it still not successfull :(

Comment: @MohammadArif You should express your appreciation of being solved by marking this answer as accepted, clicking the checkmark to the left. It's much more effective than placing "solved" in the title.

Comment: @MohammadArif : look here [Why to accept an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)